# Core 2 Duo E8400 and Intel Virtualization Technology

Tags: windows-7, intel-core2, vt-x

I have a computer with Core 2 Duo E8400 processor and ASUS P5QL-E mainboard. Recently I wanted to install XP Mode for Win 7 but I cannot run it because I'm getting an error that hardware virtualization is not enabled for my processor.

According to [this](http://processorfinder.intel.com/details.aspx?sSpec=SLAPL) my processor support VT and I checked that VT is enabled in motherboard's BIOS. But XP Mode still won't start.

I even downloaded Intel Processor Identification Utility and it also shows me that VT is off. Does anyone know how to turn it on?

Comment: which version, RTM or earlier? there are VPC RC issues with Windows 7 RC.

Comment: @Molly: Intel CPUID utility shows that VT is off - it is probably not an issue with Windows 7 RC itself.

Comment: The version is RTM.

Comment: Just an update: after getting mainnboard from the service virtualization works just fine (they flashed it with the latest BIOS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is highly possible that your BIOS has not been updated to the latest version yet - thus the missing support for VT on your E8400.

The latest version of your BIOS (v1005) can be found [here](http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=ZxpFvIAYWrjI5NY9) (you will to navigate to the Supported CPUs page). Please update your BIOS and see if VT turns on for you.

[image]

Comment: Careful! Any BIOS update has the potential to turn a nice computer into an expensive door-stop!

Comment: Of course it has the potential - but it has gotten relatively safe and painless over the years. Last time, yes. Now, still possible, but very unlikely (only if the power trips in the middle of updating).

Comment: Further, the mainboard might have an effect on whether virtualization works or not. The CPU is not the only determining factor.

Comment: ASUS update utility shows that the latest BIOS for my motherboard is 0705.

Comment: it says 1005 here on the official ASUS website. :) i suggest you get it from www.asus.com direct itself - do a search for your mobo model inside Asus website.

Comment: I just tried updating BIOS using ASUS Update utility and it went horribly wrong. It cleared the BIOS, copied the new one and failed on verification. After restart I get black screen. I guess tomorrow mainboard is going to the service.

Comment: That's why you should try getting from the website direct. When ASUS UU reported the latest BIOS is 0705, I smelled a *baaad* fish somewhere. Anyway, when you go for servicing, do try and ask them to flash the latest BIOS in for you.

Comment: I just did that. We shall see what will come up from that when they done servicing my MB. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RaYell : No need for the thanks, in fact I feel kinda bad that your mobo fried because of my suggestion to update your BIOS.

Comment: Just got my mainboard from service. After flashing BIOS virtualization works correctly.